# Program to make glider polars

Tags: glider, software, sailplane

I was using flow5 to make some speed polars for a glider with real dimensions, however I read about PGEN (polar generation software) that could simulate the thermal effect, but apparently it is an internal program at a university. I was wondering if you know of any program that is similar to include the bank angle effect, circling radius and making velocity polars for thermals,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are hoping for a treatment of circling flight that is more sophisiticated than simply increasing the wing loading as a function of the bank angle?